# orbeon forms-how to get property of a upload control in a text feild

Tags: report, orbeon

I have four upload controls in an orbeon form and I want to sum the size of the files which were uploaded using these controls in a text field.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the control names of your 4 upload fields are `my-file-1`, `my-file-2`, `my-file-3`, and `my-file-4`, you can use the following as calculated expression of, say, a *Calculated Value* control:

```
$file-1/@size + 
$file-2/@size +
$file-3/@size +
$file-4/@size
```

For instance, [this form](https://gist.github.com/avernet/cab6b88d8eebf68bf7c870211c1b605c) will show the following after you uploaded 2 files:

[image: show total size of uploaded files]